# How to check if the coordinates of the polygon are valid

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I use with `MapboxMap.ts` to draw a polygon in a map.

i get an error
`Error {message: 'Input data is not a valid GeoJSON object.'}`

How to check if the coordinates of the polygon are valid before draw the polygon?

I expected to a function like

```
isInvalidePolygon(polygon: Polygon): boolean
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a function for that on the **@turf/boolean-valid** library to which you can pass the polygon and it returns `true` or `false`:

```js
turfBoolean.booleanValid(polygon);
```

You can see more at the following [link](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/blob/master/packages/turf-boolean-valid/README.md#turfboolean-valid).